# Generating a plain index of dynamic user pages?

Tags: asp.net

My site is a business directory. Different businesses on the site have subpages that can be accessed with a URL like `http://mysite.com/businessname`. Behind the scenes, I'm using url rewriting to point those subpages to a page like `http://mysite.com/businesspage.aspx?id=[businessIDGuid]`.

I want the business pages to appear in search engines, and to do that I need to create links to them. Users can find businesses using the search tool on my site, but this isn't usable by search engines.

I thought that I should create a flat index page, with the names of every business in my database, and a link to their subpage. However, there are lots of businesses in my database (around 160,000 at the moment) so I can't really put all of them on one page. Also, the obvious way to generate these pages - having an sql query called in the `page_load` method that pulls back a list of all businesses - would put quite a lot of load on the server. It would make sense to generate a page and cache it for a day or so, but I don't know how to do this while staying within the context of asp.net.

What is the best way to generate an index of user pages in asp.net?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In summary, you need to generate a [sitemap](http://www.sitemaps.org/) and submit it to corresponding search engine.

For large sites, generating and updating a single file sitemap will be tedious task - fortunately, you can break your sitemap into multiple files and search engines like google can take a [sitemap index](http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?answer=71453) which can link to these sitemap files.

- So essentially, you need find a convenient way to break your
  businesses into groups - you can use alphabetical ordering, business
  categories, custom tags (or combination) to break them into smaller
  groups (say few hundreds to couple of thousands into a single group).
- Maintain one sitemap or page per group. Keep a table into your
  database tracking each page/sitemap and the last updated date/time
  for the same.
- You cannot use ASP.NET code to maintain these pages - instead write a small .NET console (or windows forms) program to generate/update sitemaps. Schedule the program using Windows Scheduler (Tasks) to run periodically.
- For example, you may run the program say every 15 minutes. The program would first check if there are site-maps that are to be generated (will happen first time). If yes then it will pick-up say 3-4 sitemaps and generated them. Add their entries into the log table.
- If all pages are generated then you can start updating them. So again check for last updated pages, pick 3-4 that were updated first and build them again.
- You have to adjust your scheduled period and number of pages to be generated/updated to cover entire sitemap in some target time-frame. For example, if you are running the program every 10 minutes from 8PM to 6AM every day and updates 10 site-maps per run then in a day, you will cover 600 sitemaps. If you have total 5000 sitemaps then your entire site-map will get refreshed approx every 8 days.

Comment: Great, this sound like a better idea than what I had in mind.